# groupby , Then convert the specific rows to coulmns in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

First I have this data frame:

|  | ID | Age | name | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 12 | r | y |
| 1 | 1 | 13 | c | y |
| 2 | 1 | 14 | n | y |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | m | y |
| 4 | 2 | 11 | l | N |
| 5 | 2 | 22 | k | N |
| 6 | 2 | 33 | r | N |
| 7 | 2 | 55 | l | N |

- First I want to **groupby ID** ( so I will have group 1 & 2)
- Then from the **[Age] column** in the grouped by ID dataframe, *I only need the first 2 rows and last row from each gorup* .So for group (1) from the [Age] column, I need the first row which is = 12,  the second row which is = 13 and the last row which is = 15. Surely, I need to do the same for gorup 2 as well
- and for the rest of the columns which are **[name] & [time]** in the goruped by data frame, I *only need the last row*, so for group(1), from the [name] column I need last row, which is  = m, and from the [time] column I need last row which is  = y.
- by the end I will have one row only for each ID

this is my expected/desired output:

|  | ID | Age 1 | Age 2 | Age 3 | name | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 12 | 13 | 15 | m | Y |
| 1 | 2 | 11 | 22 | 55 | l | N |

Comment: Try use `groupby().cumcount()` to get the row index within each group. From there it should be pretty easy to filter out the rwos you want. You can then try `pivot` to get those rows into your final columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df1 = df.groupby('ID').agg({'Age':lambda x:list(np.r_[x.head(2),x.tail(1)])})

df1[['name', 'time']] = df.groupby('ID')[['name', 'time']].last()

df1[['Age1', 'Age2', 'Age3']] = pd.DataFrame(df1['Age'].to_list(), index = df1.index)

df1.drop('Age', axis = 1).reset_index()

   ID name time  Age1  Age2  Age3
0   1    m    y    12    13    15
1   2    l    N    11    22    55
```

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh what do you mean by that? ie even if you have more than 4 rows, you still select the first 2 and the last 2 for Age and the last one for the other. Thanks for the upvote. Though It cannot add my points since I have reached 200 points. That the maximum per day

Comment: Thank you so much that was really really helpful , it worked Exactly as I wanted:), Thank you man

Answer (score 4):

Try with `groupby` and `pivot`:

```
#keep only the needed data
grouped = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False).agg({"Age": lambda x: x.tolist()[:2]+[x.iat[-1]], "name": "last", "time": "last"}).explode("Age")

#get the count for the age columns
grouped["idx"] = grouped.groupby("ID").cumcount().add(1)

#pivot to get the required structure
output = grouped.pivot(["ID","name","time"],"idx","Age").add_prefix("Age").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

>>> output
   ID name time Age1 Age2 Age3
0   1    m    y   12   13   15
1   2    l    N   11   22   55
```